Significantly slower compilation time after migration to Kotlin 2.0.0 from 1.9.23
I have a Spring Boot mutliproject that I just updated to Kotlin version 2.0.0 from the earlier version 1.9.23. I use IntelliJ as my IDE and ran the code migration scan tool and no warnings or errors were presented after migration but now compilation of my applications takes significantly longer.
Now, when I go to run the compileKotlin task, either on its own or as a part of the build task,  it takes up to 4x longer in my terminal (30s before migration, 120s after) and much worse when built in my IDE (up to 5.5 minutes). It seems that the compilation is very quick for the library modules within the project, the long compilation time seems to only occur during the compilation of applications within the project.
Here is a snippet of my project's root build.gradle.kts where I configure the kotlin version:
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "2.0.0" apply false
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "2.0.0" apply false
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "2.0.0" apply false
    kotlin("plugin.allopen") version "2.0.0" apply false
}

And all of my module build.gradle.kts files contain the following configuration:
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm")
    kotlin("plugin.serialization")
    `maven-publish`
    `java-library`
}

kotlin {
    compilerOptions {
        apiVersion.set(KotlinVersion.KOTLIN_2_0)
        jvmTarget.set(JvmTarget.JVM_17)
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjvm-default=all") // <-- needed to get regular JDK8 default interface methods
    }
}

The two application build.gradle.kts files contain the following configuration:
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "2.0.0"
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "2.0.0"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "2.0.0"
    kotlin("plugin.allopen") version "2.0.0"
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.3.0"
    id("org.springdoc.openapi-gradle-plugin") version "1.8.0"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.5"
    id("org.jetbrains.dokka") version "1.9.20"
    jacoco
    `maven-publish`
}

kotlin {
    compilerOptions {
        apiVersion.set(KotlinVersion.KOTLIN_2_0)
        jvmTarget.set(JvmTarget.JVM_17)
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjvm-default=all") // <-- needed to get regular JDK8 default interface methods
    }
}

Am I configuration something incorrectly? One of the biggest changes for Kotlin 2.0.0 is supposed to be significantly reduced compilation and build time so I am somewhat at a loss as to what is going on.
For good measure, I've also updated all dependencies in the projects and library modules within my repository but that did not lower compilation time whatsoever.

One thing to note, part of this body of work included upgrading to spring boot 3.3.0 from 3.2.3. Bizarrely enough, reverting back to 3.2.3 reduced compile time significantly, near my original build time.

So to be clear: If you use Kotlin 2.0.0 and Spring Boot 3.2.3, your compilation remains fast? Is this then maybe an issue with SB 3.3.0?

It is still slightly longer than my kotlin 1.9.23 compile and build time by about
@TreffnonX 3-5 seconds, but with kotlin 2.0.0 boasting much faster build and compilation times, I would have expected a performance increase, not a delay. But SB 3.3.0 was a major source of compilation time increases and I've reverted back to 3.2.3 to explore later while I complete my migration to kotlin 2.0.0
